# Couldn't the landlord just say the Thermometer doesn't work when confronted with the temperature being too low?

Tags: germany, rental-property

In Germany, from what I understand, when the temperature in apartment falls below a tolerable amount, then the renter can request the landlord for a rent reduction.

This happend to me, and I got a thermo meter, and it showed below the expected temperature. When I went to escalate with the landlord, she told my thermometer is giving wrong values.

Now, what do I do? How could I possibly escalate this?

Comment: The way to escalate this is to pay less rent - which may then lead to you getting evicted if  you're wrong or can't prove that you're right. So before doing that, you go to a lawyer, the Mieterschutzbund or similar. Ther nure are also Rechtsschutzversicherungen which offer retrospective coverage for Mietrecht, but you'd have to check, whether that applies.

Comment: Based on the question body, maybe "thermostat" in the title should be "thermometer"?

Comment: Thermostat or Thermometer? If it's the thermostat that's broken then surely it's her responsibility to fix it.

Comment: Not writing an answer, but that happened to me once. I informed them with a letter that it is too cold in my apartment. When they ignored it, I paid 50% of the rent. Next month they fixed it.

Comment: The thermometer vs. thermostat discrepancy between the title and question body needs to be clarified for this to be accurately answered. Is the landlord claiming that the _thermostat you used to measure the room temperature_ is inaccurate or are they claiming that the _thermostat used to control the heating system_ isn't working correctly? And, if it's the thermostat, is it the one that the landlord installed or did you replace it with your own (e.g. a smart thermostat or similar?)

Comment: My thermostat measures the room temperature, then turns the heating on if it is below the wanted temperature, and turns the heating off if it is above. Of course you can buy a thermometre which does just the measuring without any control, and compare their measurements.

Comment: Thermostats mounted at the heater often enough are analog devices that open or close the water inflow due to a bimetal or expanding fluid pressing the normally closed valve open when the temperature is too low. Generally, those are not set to "temperatures" at all but display numbers that are roughly temperature bands. Other thermostats have actually temperature settings. In either case, the thermostat should contol the heating. Thermometer are devices to measure temperature and **not** control the heating. Some thermostats contain thermometers of some sort.

Comment: Those very prelevant [analog thermostats often can be fixed easily](https://www.heizung.de/ratgeber/thermostate/heizkoerperventil-klemmt-die-einfache-loesung.html) by removing the thermostat and carefully pressing on the valve stem for a moment, tapping at the side of the valve or carefully turning/pulling at the pin. That should free up the pin, possibly in conjunction with WD40 or similar. Then one woiuld remount the thermostat. You might need to remove air from the heater too, to get the heater to run properly and not gurgle. Note that a 3 on the thermostat is somewhere between 18 and 22°C

Comment: Can't walk around your house taking temps. Stand in front of the T-stat with your meter. Surely they agree. You having to set the stat at 90f so that the rest of the house is at least 65f, is just a leaky house. They're required to supply you the equipment. You have to pay to run it. - If you've no control over it, *then* you walk around taking temps and complaining.

Comment: Op has answered under the highest voted answer that his room doesn't have a thermostat.

Answer (score 16):

[germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

This may seem familiar, I have quoted it before:

Quoting § 535 BGB:

> § 535 Inhalt und Hauptpflichten des Mietvertrags
> (1) Durch den Mietvertrag wird der Vermieter verpflichtet, dem Mieter den Gebrauch der Mietsache während der Mietzeit zu gewähren. Der Vermieter hat die Mietsache dem Mieter in einem zum vertragsgemäßen Gebrauch geeigneten Zustand zu überlassen **und sie während der Mietzeit in diesem Zustand zu erhalten**.

Translation:

> § Section 535 Content and main obligations of the tenancy agreement
> (1) The rental agreement obliges the landlord to grant the tenant the use of the rented property during the rental period. The landlord must leave the rented property to the tenant in a condition suitable for use in accordance with the contract **and maintain it in this condition during the rental period**.

The landlord is responsible for the proper functioning of the Thermostat just as much as for the rest of the heating.

If it doesn't work and *that* is the reason your apartment is falling below the said temperature for multiple days in a row, you can lower the rent.

Please note that to lower the rent, it must be broken in a way that makes it impossible for you to heat up the rooms using the heating system. So for example if you could heat your rooms to 20° if you set it to 25°, that is still technically broken and surely inconvenient, but not a reason to reduce rent.

> When I went to escalate with the landlord, she told my thermometer is giving wrong values.

That seems borderline stupid. The minimum temperature your landlord has to guarantee is 18°C, your heating should easily be able to give you 23-25°C if you put it that way. No thermometer is off or could be read wrong by 7°C. A thermometer *that* wrong could not differentiate between a life threatening hypothermia and life threatening fever.

I suggest you ask them over and offer them the ability to bring their own thermometer if they don't believe you.

Thermostats are nasty and sometimes not easy to handle. Especially elderly people often have problems adjusting them correctly since they became all touchscreen technological marvels, when back in the day they were a box with a single hardware knob. Last time, the service technician did not set the timezone correctly, and my neighbor had to wake up to their freezing nighttime settings every morning until I fixed it. How do you explain UTC and timezones to someone who wants to turn on their heating that is definetely not travelling across timezones any time soon?

If your themostat doesn't work, ask your landlord to call a service technician if they cannot fix the problem themselves. That is their obligation.

Comment: This answer focuses on material law. I think the question concerns procedural law.

Comment: Feel free to write an answer more in line with what you think.

Comment: Do all german rooms have a thermostat? I don't think I have one

Comment: Do you have a room or an appartment? If you have your own appartment, you should have your own thermostat. If you have a room, then the thermostat might be someplace else, but it is still the landlord's obligation to make it work for you.

Comment: "A thermometer that wrong could not differentiate between a life threatening hypothermia and life threatening fever." That is true, but not all thermometers are as precise as a fever thermometer. For room temperature measurement, 1-2° off would generally be acceptable, a fever thermometer should not be more than ~0.2° off. It only needs to work from about 32°C to 42°C, though.

Comment: @PMF But a possibly acceptable 1-2° off is still less than a third of the 7° error the answer talks of.

Comment: @TripeHound Sure, but the OP didn't say anything about how much alleged error there was in his case. I don't think it was 7°, that would indeed be ridiculous.

Comment: @trystwithfreedom The knobs on German radiators are essentially thermostats, even if they are not calibrated in terms of a numerically indicated temperature. Usually they have the settings cold/1/2/3/4/5, which map to various temperatures, that may be room-dependent; a 3 in the bathroom may be warmer than a 3 in the bedroom.  If you open everything to 5 and still cannot get to the minimum acceptable temperature, your heating is broken and your landlord is obliged to fix it.

Comment: @gerrit another alternative is, that the heaters are full of air, or the valve that is operated by the thermostat is stuck in closed - both easily fixable with minimal tools or skill. A screwdriver and maybe a square key are all that is needed

Comment: @Trish Certainly.  Landlord will appreciate if OP can fix it themselves, but if OP is unsure they have every right to ask the landlord to fix it / send somebody to fix it.

Comment: @gerrit true, unless there is a "kleinstreperaturklausel" (small repair paragraph), which puts the onus on the tennant

Comment: @trish the landlord then still has to fix it, but the tenant has to pay it. Small but big difference.

Answer (score 4):

I would argue that, at the moment, the landlord might be correct. So, before doing anything else, I'd gather more data. Buy a couple of extra thermometers, of different makes. They should be within a couple of degrees of each other.

You've then got a reasonable consensus measurement. Next, you want to get more data, using all three thermometers. You're aiming to show a sustained decrease below the permitted temperature. I would record video while taking the measurements, to show you've not just opened all the windows, or something, and take measurements 3x a day for a couple of days. Measure in all the rooms, allow thermometers to acclimatise to each room before reading, and make sure to include the radiator settings in the video each time.

The nice thing here is that it might also help figure out what is wrong - a radiator in one of the rooms might not be working, in which case, bleeding it might fix it.

If there's nothing obvious, but the heating still can't get up to a reasonable temperature, you've got a vastly improved case for taking action - not just a couple of measurements with a possibly accurate thermometer.

At that point, I'd start discussing how they can either fix it or start losing rent.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to test the thermometers by dunking in ice-water (zero degrees) then in boiling water (100 degrees) It is a reasonable assumption that if those two points read correctly, then anything in between is correct too. If the thermometer doesn't reach either of those two extremes, it isn't worth relying on in the first place.

Comment: Be careful with the upper bounds. While I like the scientific test, do not put thermometers for measuring room temperature in boiling water or a really cold freezer. They are probably not meant for that and it might not be safe! A cheap room thermometer that goes from -20 to 50 should never reach their respective limits anywhere in Germany naturally and will certainly not be safe for going over those limits.

Comment: I'd like to add that the themometer the topic originator bought is probably correct, but before you take action like reducing the rent you pay, you want to have excellent proof of this.

Comment: @MikeB unless it's a digital thermometer designed to measure ambient air temperature, in which case immersing it will probably cause it to stop working.  Even an analogue thermometer with a bimetallic strip is unlikely to handle immersion very well.

Comment: @lupe in jurisdictions I'm familiar with there is a very specific procedure required for paying reduced rent, so it is probably a good idea to check with a local L&T lawyer or at least s tenant's rights organization before reducing rent payments.

Answer (score 3):

### What is the accuracy and precision of the thermometer and when was it last calibrated?

All scientific instruments (including thermometers) have varying degrees of accuracy and precision:

[image: Precission vs Accuracy]

Both are sources of inaccuracy in measurement. Calibration can reduce inaccuracy, but precision is a function of the instrument itself and its operating conditions.

You don’t tell us what sort of thermometer you are using but if it is a cheap alcohol filled tube that you might buy in a souvenir store, it has probably never been calibrated and might be out by several degrees. If it’s a reasonable electronic one such as you might buy in a hardware store, errors are likely to be in the order of a degree or so providing it’s new or recently calibrated. If it’s a high precision laboratory instrument with recent calibration errors could be less than a tenth of a degree. Consult the literature that came with the instrument, it will tell you all about its accuracy and precision. If it didn’t come with literature, you might as well not bother.

In addition, *how* you measure the temperature is also going to matter. You should be measuring in several positions in the room and be using the median temperature. You need to be away from walls, doors, and windows and out of drafts. You also need to repeat the measurements in the same places at the same time over several days.

If you present this kind of robust data, it will be very hard for anyone to argue against it. As the person asserting the fact (it’s too cold), the onus rests on the tenant to prove it.

Comment: Why would it be the OP's burden to prove accuracy & precision vs the landlord having to prove the opposite?

Comment: @Greendrake because the tenant accuses the landlord that he didn't do his obligations. The burden of proof lies with the accusing party.

Comment: @Trish that's kinda silly.   Thermometers are measuring instruments.   What kind of certification are you conceptualizing requiring to prove the accuracy?   A thermometer purchased from any store should have an assumption of accuracy and reliability.   You say it is cold, you purchase a measuring device to prove it, and it says it's too cold.   If the landlord wants to dispute the accuracy of your device, they can purchase their own measuring device and check the temperature themselves.  If their device reads different enough, you can both bring them to court.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat The landlord is obligated to have a working heating. The tenant claims the heating is defect and has to at least show that *something* has to be fixed in some way. "It feels cold" is not sufficient. "I have the heating on full power but it is 12°C" would be. Only *now*, that the tenant showed the defect, the landlord has to act, fixing the problem and either paying for it because it was his error, or showing that the problem was caused by the tenant and billing the tenant. Just claiming "the heating is defect" without even showing that it is cold in the flat is not going to fly.

Comment: @Trish OP says it was too cold.   OP got a thermometer showing it was too cold.   How is that not 'showing that it is cold in the flat'?  OP has provided enough proof.   If the landlord wants to say that OP's thermometer is 'showing the wrong numbers', the landlord has to provide some contradictory evidence.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat the OP has provided evidence and the landlord has questioned the reliability of that evidence. As the person making the assertion (it’s too cold) the onus is on the tenant to prove it with robust and reliable evidence. Without that it’s a case of “is” vs “isn’t”. The landlord wins that argument.

Comment: Germany must have different rules of evidence.    In the US the tenant would be sworn in, would testify they bought and used the thermometer and what temperature it read.   The landlord saying "that might be wrong" wouldn't be good enough.  Without the landlord giving contradictory evidence, the only evidence available would favor the tenant.   The standard in civil trials isn't beyond a reasonable doubt like in criminal trials.  What *exact* standard of evidence do you require?  Experts?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat it's not that different. The risk is that in court the landlord may have Googled the specification of your thermometer and it that's all you have and the specs are bad or the landlord tests your thermometer via an expert, you might lose the case and pay the cost. If the landlord doesn't have anything more than "I don't believe it" you're chances after good. But for going to court, you should gather good evidence, not just evidence that works *maybe*. And of course if the answer to "how old is that thermometer" is "...", at some point, the credibility of your evidence suffers.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat "Without the landlord giving contradictory evidence, the only evidence available would favor the tenant": that's not how it works in the US.  When you get a speeding ticket, the police will testify that their radar gun was calibrated or tested at the beginning of their shift.  Why?  Because otherwise you can say "it might be wrong" and they can't counter it.  The "only evidence available" is only as valuable as it is credible. For example, the tenant saying "it showed 15 degrees" is less credible than a photo of the thermometer showing 15 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert in law, but I do know that precisely calibrated thermometers are a lot more affordable these days than they used to be.

For example, I have [this one from switchbot](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/SwitchBot-Thermometer-Hygrometer-Bluetooth-Temperature/dp/B09QBR7XJD/) which advertises ±0.2°C accuracy - and the manufacturers of the sensing chip offer calibration certificates to that effect. The range of temperatures people find comfortable is fairly narrow, so you want to know the measurement is right.

My country does not have the same rental protections as Germany has - but when I lived in a rental property with faulty heating and the landlord was unresponsive to my complaints, I brought myself a cheap fan heater which I ran as needed. This kept me warm, and was within my rights as a tenant.

Comment: Electricity is expensive in Germany. I wouldn't want to run a cheap fan heater on my dime and if electricity was included in the rent the landlord would react by increasing rent. Also, the wiring/breaker might not be able to support it and it might even be a fire hazard.